# Java: string literal behaves differently from string variable (cannot be from interning)

Tags: java, string, string-literals

I have the following code:

```
public RecordList searchDatabase(String key, String value)
{
    String newKey;

    newKey = key; // no results
    //newKey = "name_of_person"; // finds results
    //newKey = new String("name"); // no results
    //newKey = new String(key); // no results
    //newKey = new String(key.getBytes().clone()); // no results

    System.out.println(newKey.equals("name_of_person"));

    return database.search(newKey, value);
}
```

It is supposed to search a database with a key and value, but it finds nothing. But if I change the key to a string literal (the first commented line), it finds the correct results. I tried a few other things (the other commented lines), which didn't work. The println always prints true.

I searched for similar problems, and it seems that interning is a common cause for problems with string comparison. But in this case, the only case that works is when I pass a string literal, so if interning is the problem, then the database must have the field as a string literal in its source. 
I searched, and the literal "name_of_person" does not appear elsewhere in the source (it is dynamically created from JSON).

In case it matters, the database.search function is [org.apache.lucene.search.join.JoinUtil](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-join/3.6.2/org/apache/lucene/search/join/JoinUtil.java).createJoinQuery, and the problem is with its 2nd parameter, toField.

Comment: The database search function is not going to be breaking due to interning - as far as I know the only reference-sensitive operation on strings is checking for identity rather than equality ("==" vs .equals).

Comment: I guess im curious as to what the database object does. Personally id assume key is the string value of the table... if the database object is a big data store... then its the value of an edge. Seems the value name_of_person is the name of a table column, a table, a node, or an edge. I would assume a lookup (name_of_person, "persons_name") to be performed. Is this a bad assumption?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your assumption. The actual database is Lucene, it has a collection of so-called documents, each document has a collection of key-value pairs, and database.search("name_of_person", "Bill") should return all documents that contain the key-value pair ("name_of_person", "Bill"). Does this help?

Comment: Sure you did not simplify and actually working is `newKey = Constants.NAME_OF_PERSON;` - some imported constant? These can get stale. Debugging seems the only way.

Comment: I have the same problem when dealing with Cookie values and HttpRequest.... can't use variable!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasonable explanation:

1. the `search()` method of the `database` object's class is using `==` to compare the `key` parameter with `"name_of_person"`, instead of `equals()`.
2. Your key value has trailing whitespace characters, like a trailing blank

Try this:

```
key = key.trim();
```

Comment: I searched the source of the database, and "name_of_person" does not appear there.

Comment: It can be a concatenation of other literals. As long as the compiler can determine a string value it will be interned. Debug the app and you'll find the problem

Comment: I suppose that's theoretically possible, but it wouldn't make sense. The database is field-name-agnostic - you can create a field with any name you can think of. So it doesn't make sense to hardcode field names in the source.

Comment: Anyway, I just tried changing "name_of_person" to "foryubslfhsdaf", and the same problem still happens. I'm pretty sure the database doesn't contain a compiler-determinable string value equal to "foryubslfhsdaf". EDIT: I made the change in my code, and did not recompile the database, so it is impossible for the change to have affected the compilation of the database.

Comment: Fair enough - good trat. I can't think why you are seeing what you're seeing, unless you have some whitespace characters in your key, like a trailing space. See edit